# PHP regular expression with preg_match_all - why doesn't it match?

Tags: php, regex-greedy

I'm looking at a regular expression to match any characters. I know that the '.' is a placeholder except for newline. Given this code below:

```
$fruits = "One\nTwo\nThree";
preg_match_all('/^(.*)$/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Why does it not match anything at all? I would think, $matches[0] would be One Two Three?

Comment: Odd.  Your code works for me.

Comment: It works just fine: http://rubular.com/r/is69Ug3qNN
Look at the @irrelephant comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [modifier "s" to the regex](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class
>   such as [^a] always matches a newline character, independent of the
>   setting of this modifier.

```
$fruits = "One\nTwo\nThree";
preg_match_all('/^(.*)$/s', $fruits, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Update:**

If you enclose $fruits in single quotes, the newline isn't treated as such and the replacement also works, event without the "s" modifier. But I don't know if the output is what you expect it to be ;)

```
   $fruits = 'One\nTwo\nThree';
   preg_match_all('/^(.*)$/', $fruits, $matches);
   print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Also, if your regex engine doesn't support the `s` modifier or similar, or you only want its behaviour in one area, you can use `[\s\S]`.